# Using twitter4j to find an exact tweet, by status_id

Tags: search, twitter4j, reply

I'm using twitter4j to stream all statuses with a reply_id, and (trying to get) the status they are replying to. So I stream a bunch of statuses, and on each one do:

```
Long replyID=status.getInReplyToStatusId();
```

but then I don't know what to do with my `replyID` variable to actually find the associated tweet.

(I'm very, very new to twitter4j and the Twitter API)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the replyId to get the actual tweet like :

Status tweet = twitter.showStatus(parent);

BTW what do you mean when you say " stream all statuses with a reply_id",can you elaborate ?